# Error on JSON Parser.JSONException and error executing doInBackground().AsyncTask

Tags: json, authentication, android-asynctask, network-programming

I'm try to execute small application on network, that is Login application. Using Asynch Task and doitinBackground, but go the  error as above.

I'm new on Android, could someone help on identifying the problem and the cause of the error ?

Thanks a lot.

My Login.java code :

```
    package com.lm.mktproapp12;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;

    import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
    import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
    import org.json.JSONException;
    import org.json.JSONObject;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.app.ProgressDialog;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.AsyncTask;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    public class Login extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

    private EditText user, pass;
    private Button mSubmit, mRegister;

    private ProgressDialog pDialog;


    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();


    private static final String LOGIN_URL = "http://192.168.0.254/webservice/login.php";

    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_MESSAGE = "message";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.login);

    user = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.username);
    pass = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.password);

    mSubmit = (Button)findViewById(R.id.login);
    mRegister = (Button)findViewById(R.id.register);

    mSubmit.setOnClickListener(this);
    mRegister.setOnClickListener(this);

}


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.login:
            new AttemptLogin().execute();
        break;
    case R.id.register:
            Intent i = new Intent(this, Register.class);
            startActivity(i);
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }
}

class AttemptLogin extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

     /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    boolean failure = false;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Login.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Attempting login...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         // Check for success tag
        int success;
        String username = user.getText().toString();
        String password = pass.getText().toString();
        try {
            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));

            Log.d("request!", "starting");
            // getting product details by making HTTP request
            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                   LOGIN_URL, "POST", params);

            // check your log for json response
            Log.d("Login attempt", json.toString());

            // json success tag
            success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
            if (success == 1) {
                Log.d("Login Successful!", json.toString());
                Intent i = new Intent(Login.this, ReadComments.class);
                finish();
                startActivity(i);
                return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
            }else{
                Log.d("Login Failure!", json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE));
                return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);

            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;

    }
    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        pDialog.dismiss();
        if (file_url != null){
            Toast.makeText(Login.this, file_url, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }

}
```

}

Messages Fatal Exception.... as below :

```
    07-03 13:47:20.229: I/System.out(15315): [CDS]rx timeout:0
    07-03 13:47:20.229: I/System.out(15315): [CDS]shutdownInput in read
    07-03 13:47:20.229: I/System.out(15315): [CDS]close[60033]
    07-03 13:47:20.230: I/System.out(15315): close [socket]   [/0.0.0.0:60033]
    07-03 13:47:20.230: I/System.out(15315): close [socket][/0.0.0.0:60033]
    07-03 13:47:20.230: E/JSON Parser(15315): ***Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of*** 
    07-03 13:47:20.231: D/dalvikvm(15315): create interp thread : stack size=128KB
    07-03 13:47:20.231: D/dalvikvm(15315): create new thread
    07-03 13:47:20.231: D/dalvikvm(15315): new thread created
    07-03 13:47:20.231: D/dalvikvm(15315): update thread list
    07-03 13:47:20.231: D/dalvikvm(15315): threadid=20: interp stack at 0x64348000
    07-03 13:47:20.231: D/dalvikvm(15315): threadid=20: created from interp
    07-03 13:47:20.231: D/dalvikvm(15315): start new thread
    07-03 13:47:20.231: D/dalvikvm(15315): threadid=12: exiting
    07-03 13:47:20.231: W/dalvikvm(15315): threadid=12: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x421ae9a8)
    07-03 13:47:20.231: W/dalvikvm(15315): threadid=12: ***uncaught exception occurred***
    07-03 13:47:20.233: W/System.err(15315):   ***java.lang.RuntimeException:     
    An error occured while executing doInBackground()***
    07-03 13:47:20.234: D/dalvikvm(15315): threadid=20: notify debugger
    07-03 13:47:20.234: ***W/System.err(15315):     at   android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:2***99)
    07-03 13:47:20.234: W/System.err(15315):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
    07-03 13:47:20.234: W/System.err(15315):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
    07-03 13:47:20.234: W/System.err(15315):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
    07-03 13:47:20.234: W/System.err(15315):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
    07-03 13:47:20.234: W/System.err(15315):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
    07-03 13:47:20.234: W/System.err(15315):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:838)
    07-03 13:47:20.234: W/System.err(15315): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    07-03 13:47:20.234: W/System.err(15315):    at com.lm.mktproapp12.Login$AttemptLogin.doInBackground(Login.java:136)
    07-03 13:47:20.235: W/System.err(15315):    at com.lm.mktproapp12.Login$AttemptLogin.doInBackground(Login.java:1)
    07-03 13:47:20.235: W/System.err(15315):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
    07-03 13:47:20.235: W/System.err(15315):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
    07-03 13:47:20.235: W/System.err(15315):    ... 3 more
    07-03 13:47:20.235: W/dalvikvm(15315): threadid=12: calling UncaughtExceptionHandler
    07-03 13:47:20.235: E/AndroidRuntime(15315): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
    07-03 13:47:20.235: E/AndroidRuntime(15315): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
    07-03 13:47:20.235: E/AndroidRuntime(15315):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
    07-03 13:47:20.235: E/AndroidRuntime(15315):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
    07-03 13:47:20.235: E/AndroidRuntime(15315):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
    07-03 13:47:20.235: E/AndroidRuntime(15315):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
    07-03 13:47:20.235: E/AndroidRuntime(15315):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
    07-03 13:47:20.235: E/AndroidRuntime(15315):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
    07-03 13:47:20.235: E/AndroidRuntime(15315):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:838)
    07-03 13:47:20.235: E/AndroidRuntime(15315): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    07-03 13:47:20.235: E/AndroidRuntime(15315):    at com.lm.mktproapp12.Login$AttemptLogin.doInBackground(Login.java:136)
    07-03 13:47:20.235: E/AndroidRuntime(15315):    at com.lm.mktproapp12.Login$AttemptLogin.doInBackground(Login.java:1)
    07-03 13:47:20.235: E/AndroidRuntime(15315):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
    07-03 13:47:20.235: E/AndroidRuntime(15315):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
    07-03 13:47:20.235: E/AndroidRuntime(15315):    ... 3 more
    07-03 13:47:20.236: D/dalvikvm(15315): threadid=20 (AsyncTask #6): calling run()
    07-03 13:47:20.240: I/MiuiCursorController(15315): InsertionPointCursorController is hidden including all panels and handle
    07-03 13:47:20.240: I/MiuiCursorController(15315): InsertionPointCursorController is hidden including all panels and handle
    07-03 13:47:20.249: D/GraphicBuffer(15315): create handle(0x620ef420) (w:688, h:192, f:1)
    07-03 13:47:20.325: D/GraphicBuffer(15315): close handle(0x6152eea8) (w:688 h:192 f:1)
    07-03 13:47:20.339: D/GraphicBuffer(15315): close handle(0x620ef420) (w:688 h:192 f:1)
```

My JSON Parser as below :

```
    package com.lm.mktproapp12;

    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStream;
    import java.io.InputStreamReader;
    import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
    import java.util.List;

    import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
    import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
    import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
    import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
    import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
    import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
    import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
    import org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils;
    import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
    import org.json.JSONException;
    import org.json.JSONObject;

    import android.util.Log;

    public class JSONParser {

      static InputStream is = null;
      static JSONObject jObj = null;
      static String json = "";


     public JSONParser() {

           }


     public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
        List<NameValuePair> params) {


        try {


        if(method == "POST"){
            // request method is POST
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();

        }else if(method == "GET"){
            // request method is GET
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
            url += "?" + paramString;
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();
        }           

       } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
       } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
       } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
       }

       try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }


        try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }


        return jObj;

        }
        }
```

And my php , login.php coding :

```
    <?php

     //load and connect to MySQL database stuff
     require("config.inc.php");

     if (!empty($_POST)) {
     //gets user's info based off of a username.
     $query = " 
        SELECT 
            id, 
            username, 
            password
        FROM users 
        WHERE 
            username = :username 
         ";

       $query_params = array(
       ':username' => $_POST['username']
        );

        try {
         $stmt   = $db->prepare($query);
         $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);
          }
         catch (PDOException $ex) {
         // For testing, you could use a die and message. 
        //die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage());

          //or just use this use this one to product JSON data:
         $response["success"] = 0;
         $response["message"] = "Database Error1. Please Try Again!";
         die(json_encode($response));

         }


        //we initialize it as false.
        $validated_info = false;

        //fetching all the rows from the query
        $row = $stmt->fetch();
         if ($row) {
          if ($_POST['password'] === $row['password']) {
        $login_ok = true;
         }
         }


       if ($login_ok) {
        $response["success"] = 1;
        $response["message"] = "Login successful!";
        die(json_encode($response));
       } else {
       $response["success"] = 0;
       $response["message"] = "Invalid Credentials!";
       die(json_encode($response));
       }
        } else {
       ?>
       <h1>Login</h1> 
       <form action="login.php" method="post"> 
        Username:<br /> 
        <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="username" /> 
        <br /><br /> 
        Password:<br /> 
        <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password" value="" /> 
        <br /><br /> 
        <input type="submit" value="Login" /> 
        </form> 
        <a href="register.php">Register</a>
        <?php
        }

        ?>
```

Comment: Additionally, after the exception in makeHTTPRequest you are returning null which later causes a null pointer exception. Can you log (and show) the value of string json before creating the json object? Surely you are receiving a wrong json

Comment: It seems json string is empty

Answer (score 0):

json string is empty.

Is the server sending data encoded with iso-8859-1 or utf-8? I think you are receiving it in utf-8

Don't you need to add header "Accept" in your request?

```
request.setHeader("Accept", "Application/Json");
```

Comment: HI Rodolk, the server send the data in UTF-8, is it cause of the MySQL Database  definition of the data it self ? And about header "accept", where should I put it ? I will try that. Your advice is very much appreciated.and thanks a lot.

Comment: @LeonardMamangkey, Look at the line " BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8); " , you are using iso-8859-1. Try utf-8 or default instead. Also please print value of that string to see if it is actually empty.

Comment: Finally, solved the problem with :  BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "utf-8")); and : StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line);